# Did anyone noticed this problem in wordpress?

Tags: wordpress, image

I found a weird bug, in cropping image in wordpress

I used WP_Customize_Cropped_Image_Control to crop image. In there I set the width 750 & height 500

that works well but that was showing error while cropping some other image

*It made me crazy, after spending so many hour, I realized that (the error and not showing cropping frame) it occur with the images
which have the same aspect ratio as I provided in WP_Customize_Cropped_Image_Control (if the aspect ratio matched then error occur)

if I don't provide aspect the ratio and set flex width and height then it works well

*Other thing I noticed that I have a wide image that is 1920 X 742
which takes the whole width of Crop Image modal of Wordpress, so there is also causing error (not showing cropping frame and showing error)

If I resize my browser window then It show the cropping frame and can crop the image without any error

Comment: I have the exact same problems that you mentioned in your question. I was searching for the problem for hours at last I came across your question and at least I can also say that it seems a bug. Did you find a workaround for this?

Answer (score 0):

After some long research, I understood that it is a known bug of a jQuery library that is used by Wordpress and this library has not been updated for a long time. There is a workaround but it is a bit tricky. If you really need it, here is the solution for the curious ones:
The file is  `/wp-includes/js/imgareaselect/jquery.imgareaselect.js`
Copy your own version (do not make a change in core WP files) and put it like somewhere in your template directory for example a `js` directory. Find this code snippet:

```
imgWidth = $img.innerWidth();
imgHeight = $img.innerHeight();
```

change it to this

```
imgWidth = Math.ceil($img.innerWidth());
imgHeight = Math.ceil($img.innerHeight());
```

Then you should dequeue and deregister the core file and enqueue your version. In case you do not know how to do it, I also put it here for the ones who need it.
Put the code snippet in your functions.php file.

```
// change custom scripts example
add_action( 'wp_print_scripts', 'cleanup_scripts', PHP_INT_MAX);
add_action( 'wp_print_footer_scripts', 'cleanup_scripts', PHP_INT_MAX);
function cleanup_scripts() {
    wp_deregister_script('imgareaselect');
    wp_dequeue_script('imgareaselect');
    wp_enqueue_script('imgareaselect', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/jquery.imgareaselect.min.js', array('jquery'), '1.0', true);
}
```

'imgareaselect' is the handle of the file that is used by Wordpress core.
I also put the source here in case you want to dig deeper.
https://github.com/google/web-stories-wp/issues/8398